# Top navigation bar disabled

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to handle remote notification.
In my didReceive method in AppDelegate, I'm trying to open a view :

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InfoTraficViewController") as? InfoTraficViewController
        destinationController?.infoTraficId = trafficInfoId
        window?.rootViewController?.present(destinationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is working, but the top navigation bar is not shown. So the user cannot go previous.

What can I do ? I tried :

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
```

But it's not working

EDIT :

It's working with :

```
 var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InfoTraficViewController") as? InfoTraficViewController
    destinationController?.infoTraficId = trafficInfoId

    var customUiNavController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomUINavigationController") as? CustomUINavigationController
    customUiNavController?.pushViewController(destinationController!, animated: true)

    window?.rootViewController = customUiNavController
```

Thanks to Rajat

Comment: your `windows`s rootViewController should be a `navController`, did you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
window?.rootViewController?.present(destinationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with this

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationController, animated: true)
```

As the issue is, you are presenting your `UIViewController` on the `rootViewController` of `window`, so this `ViewController` is on top of your `UINavigationController`.

Comment: cannot use self.navigationController on AppDelegate

Comment: with window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController, nothing at all is pushed

Comment: create an object of UINavigationController in AppDelegate and assign it to your UINavigationController's object then use that object in appdelegate

Comment: `print` that object and check it is not nil

Comment: oh, now it's working, I will accept your answer and edit my post with the right code, thank you for helping